# Vim not encoding with UTF-8

Tags: encoding, linux-arch

I'm using Vim, installed from the Arch Linux repo.

I've tried adding `set fileencodings=utf-8` and `set encoding=utf-8`. I've tried with all caps (UTF instead of utf) and putting it in `/etc/vimrc` and `~/.vimrc`.

More over, I tried writing a file as UTF-8 using `:write ++enc=utf-8` but that didn't work either.

I'm testing the files with `file test` and it keeps telling me it's ASCII text. This is a problem since I use non-ASCII characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I feel like an idiot. The test file doesn't have any non-ASCII characters in it, so there is nothing for `file` to look for that would tell it the encoding Vim is using. So I repeated the test with `ä` in it and it returns "utf-8" as desired.

In short, `file` was doing its best, and Vim was doing what I wanted it to do.

Comment: `file` doesnt always do so well, anyways. You can trick its heuristics, iirc